# What sort of date is this in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a date I need to replicate in PHP. I just want to know if there is some sort of shortcode for it.

```
2013-05-09T15:23:59.802Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one liner achieves what you are asking.

```
echo date_format(date_create("@".$unix_timestamp, timezone_open('UTC')), 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z');
```

Output:

```
2013-05-09T15:23:59.000Z
```

Answer (score 2):

It is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). In PHP you would make it using:

```
echo date('c'); // as of PHP 5
```

See [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: The ISO allows for differing levels of precision etc.  If you want it just like you showed I believe you will have to assemble it yourself with `date` / `DateTime`.